# Error: compobj.dll is too old for the ole2.dll initialized (Exception from HRESULT:0x8004000E(OLE_E_WRONGCOMPOBJ))

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I am trying to write a simple dialer to broadcast events for a local women's group (so no money for commercial app) and downloaded http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10994/TAPI-Application-development-using-C-NET I am getting the following error:

compobj.dll is too old for the ole2.dll initialized (Exception from HRESULT:0x8004000E(OLE_E_WRONGCOMPOBJ))

I have 2 copies of each dll on my machine and they are all from 8/21/2013.

I am running Microsoft Windows 8.1 (64-bit) and using VS Express 2013 for Win. Desktop

Comment: Did you build the code yourself, or try to run a pre-built executable?

Comment: @Baldrick I'm building the code myself.

Comment: Maybe this link can help:"

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6e45ae65-7be0-4c9e-8989-df413028639d/compobjdll-is-too-old-for-the-ole2dll-initialized

Comment: @Neill Verreynne Yes that link did help. if fact I saw it already but misunderstood which like of code need to be fixed, so thank you for bringing it to my attention again. Alas, the code still doesn't work, no errors it just doesn't work, I'm convinced after searching hi and low and testing different sets of code there isn't a strait foreword (read easy and cheep) way to accomplish an auto-dialer in win8 :(